# How do I create a button that calls a method in a controller without changing views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an ActionLink that I would like to call my method in my controller however I don't want it to change views.  The ActionLink sends an ID to the controller which it needs but it then tries to access a view that doesn't exist.  I need the link to trigger my method but not attempt to change views, I also don't want it to show the route information in the address bar either.

Here is the button, it has the label text the method it needs to call and the controller name.  As you can see there is an ID at the end as well (the ## is for Kendo)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Prompt", "buttonPrompt", "Home", new { id= "/#=vessel_idx# "}, null)
```

When I click that link it tries to access the view (which doesn't exist)

```
/Home/buttonPrompt/id
```

Here is the controller

```
public void buttonPrompt(int? id)
{
    .. my code ....
}
```

So I need to know how I can call my buttonPrompt method without changing views or showing the route info in the address bar of the browser.  Is this possible or is my approach wrong?

Comment: buttonPrompt is not Action in mvc.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There may be other ways to solve your issue, if you can share more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

### View page code:

```
<input type="button" id="yourBtn" value="Click Me!" />
```

### Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#yourBtn").click(function(){
        var id = **YourIntValue**
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("ButtonPrompt","Home")",
            type: "GET",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
                alert("Error" + errorThrown)
            },
            success: function(data){
                //Do nothing
            }
        });
    });
```

### Controller:

```
public ActionResult ButtonPrompt(int? id)
{
    .. your code ....
    return Json(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Currently you are making GET requests that means that the parameters are set in the url. You should make a post request which would again make a page reload but would put your parameters in the request body of the http context. You can read about Form posting in MVC also check out this fairly short example: https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX to call the controller action (method). First of all, give your link an id like 'btnPrompt':

```
@Html.ActionLink("Prompt", "buttonPrompt", "Home", new { id= "/#=vessel_idx# "}, htmlAttributes: new { id = "btnPrompt" })
```

Secondly, use jQuery to make an ajax call to the action:

```
$('#btnPrompt').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // this gives you /Home/buttonPrompt/123

    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            // do nothing here, unless you're returning JSON from your action
        }
    });
});
```

The line `e.preventDefault();` stops your  link from actually following the href (or "changing views", as you call it).